# How to UN-declare all non-function variables added via JavaScript console (without refreshing)

Tags: javascript, console, devtools

Consider this - Say I went to console and wrote:

```
let x = 'y';
```

I then wrote again and got:

```
let x = 'y';
```

I'll get the:

> SyntaxError: redeclaration of let x

Of course I've no intention to do so and it's just to describe how I get the error.

Sometimes I copy whole code with variable redeclarations several times for **testing** purposes, and these codes contain code with variables already declared (even though I modified other parts of the code in a text editor before copying it). To overcome this I should refresh the browser.

What could I write in console to no longer have this "redeclaration" error?

I tried this which didn't help:

```
localStorage.clear();
```

In other words, how to UN-declare variables (**which aren't functions**) after I declared them in the JS console?

---

The reason I ask this is comfortability --- I prefer to undeclare all variables without refreshing in most cases.

This could be enuormosly comfortable when **testing CSS injections** as in this case (this way you don't get "redeclaration of `myCSS`):

```
// JS CODE TO UN-DECLARE ALL VARIABLES IN EACH NEW PASTE.

// CODE WITH SAME VARIABLES AND CHANGES:
let myCss =`
    .myclass1 {opacity: 1}
    .myclass2 {display: block}
`;
style = document.createElement("style");
style.type = "text/css";
style.styleSheet ? style.styleSheet.cssText = myCss : style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(myCss) );
head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
head.appendChild(style);
```

Comment: This console is for debugging your application and whatever you type in console will impact the same session. You can **1)** Either create a invisible frame and declare your variables in that iFrame **2)** or Use IIFE and declare your variables in it so that global namespace is not polluted

Comment: When you are referring to console, what browser or devtools do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)'s:

```
(function () { 
    let x = 'y'; 
    console.log(x); 
})();
```

They do not create the variables under the global namespace. Hence you could run the IIFE multiple times without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete a variable that has been declared directly in console using var/let/const.

You have two options, either use an IIFE (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression).

This works as everything is function scoped.

Or don't use var/let/const

```
x = "y";
delete x;
x = "z";
```